# How can I atomically add a new key to google appengine's memcache?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, concurrency, memcached

I'd like to *atomically add* a new key to google appengine's memcache service using the Java API. This means that the put operation should fail (e.g. throw an exception or return `false` ) if the key is already present in the memcache, preventing concurrent additions (which would result in overwriting) to the memcache.

I don't see how this can be accomplished with the `getIdentifiable` / `putIfUntouched` pair of methods. Also, `synchronize` does not help because I want control concurrency across different instances of my servlet.

Comment: What do you mean by "preventing concurrent additions"? There are several possible strategies: don't write if present, over-write if present, or fire exception if present.

Comment: Why not just synchronize the block doing the adding?

Comment: Don't write if present, or fire an exception would be what I want. Essentially, what I want to prevent is over-write if present.

Comment: `synchronize` would not do what I want, I think, because I want to control concurrent additions across different instances of my servlet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to put with SetPolicy.ADD_ONLY_IF_NOT_PRESENT that will only write a value if the key does not exist already.

```
boolean put(java.lang.Object key,
      java.lang.Object value,
      Expiration expires,
      MemcacheService.SetPolicy policy)
```

The return value will tell you if a value already existed.